# Webpage Won't Update on IIS7

Tags: .net, caching, iis-7, coldfusion, cfml

I have a website and the static content on the page won't update no matter what I try to do. On the server the page is updated, but viewing it in the browser, you still see the same old page. I have administrator rights on the server (IIS 7) and here's whawt I've done thus far....

I clicked on teh server name and selected "Output Caching" then I did the following: 
[image]

This did not help. Is there anything else I can do to make the server stop caching the static content?

Comment: What happens when you restart the coldfusion server? Does the page update after that?

Comment: sometimes in IIS when we face this problem we delete the destination file and reupload (instead of just overwriting it) from the source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ColdFusion Administrator, go to **Server Settings** > **Caching**. Click **Clear Template Cache Now** and **Clear Component Cache Now**.

Comment: This solution is independent of IIS. ColdFusion by default caches templates and components after they've run the first time. This is done for performance. But sometimes it doesn't realize it's time to release the cached versions, so you manually clear them via CF Administrator. If you have old hard-coded content in your CFM files that is still being served up, but your dynamic content is correct, then CF is caching the CFM template. If your hard-coded content and your dynamic content are both not updating correctly, then caching is occurring at the web server level.

Comment: @imthepitts...thanks for helping me, but I just don't know where the "Coldfusion Administrator" is located in IIS. I've inherited this and I'm working hard to understand it. Is the CF administrator a URL? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I assumed you know where that was. ColdFusion Administrator (for most installations) is located in a virtual directory called /CFIDE/administrator. So browse the root of your site with that tacked on the end. Example: http://www.awesomesitename.com/CFIDE/administrator. You'll likely need the admin login to access it. If you don't have access to that login and no one else administering the server knows about it, you may need to crack into it. Here's instructions to do that: https://support.gearhost.com/KB/a532/how-to-reset-your-coldfusion-administrator-password.aspx